Why is AWS Athena converting my floats when reading parquet files in S3?
I have a pipeline that received JSON files and converts them to parquet tabular format to store in S3. Next, I have Athena tables set up which query the S3 bucket to surface the data. In the parquet files, I have a float field which has values, for example 400000000; however, when querying in Athena, all nonzero values are converted to very tiny numbers. 400000000 is converted to 1.3927371E-24; other values are converted to E-43 to E-38.
I have tried casting the values to a different type in the query, but with no success. I downloaded the parquet and opened in pandas and I see the correct values so I can't figure out the problem.
